# Declustering spatial data and kriging

Tags: geostatistics, kriging, variogram

I am doing a simple project on a mining dataset and came across some problems:

1. Should I use the declustered values to model the variogram?
2. Do I apply ordinary kriging to the original or to the declustered values?

Also, it is worth saying that I applied the cell method for declustering and eventually, as the more densely sampled regions are near to weight 0, I feel like the deposit has changed a lot in terms of continuity. It feels wrong using the declustered values, but in theory, I believe it is correct, as it does penalize the regions which are more densely sampled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forgot to answer my own question:

1. Due to the nature of the data, declustering would remove certain data points, which affects the overall distribution and variability of the data - so it is not recommended to do this.
2. According to [this article](https://www.ccgalberta.com/ccgresources/report04/2002-124-declusterdebias-ccg.pdf) I can apply kriging to the original data as it will be weighted by the process.

Thanks!